# Why is my Recursive Fibonacci implementation written in C++ segfaulting?

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I'm having a hard time understanding why

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fib(int x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << fib(5) << endl;
}
```

results in a segmentation fault. Once x gets down to 1 shouldn't it eventually return?

Comment: The time complexity of this algorithm is O(2^n). It is very bad.
For exapmle, f(30) calculation required about 1 billion operations.
Use the dynamic programming in your case.

Comment: @Alexey, I'm sure the OP just wants to learn. If performance is an issue, Meta-programming is really the way to go.

Comment: The segmentation fault is the symptom of a stack overflow.

Comment: Try stepping through the code in the debugger, you should be able to see the point where something goes wrong...

Comment: I like to joke (or not) that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(fib(n)).

Answer (score 151, accepted):

When `x==2` you call `fib(1)` and `fib(0)`:

```
return fib(2-1)+fib(2-2);
```

Consider what will happen when `fib(0)` is evaluated...

Comment: +1 for not giving the answer directly but indicating where the problem is.  Much better for someone who is learning.

Comment: +1, I use the same technique with my oldest kid (9) and it stimulates his ability to solve problems.

Answer (score 40):

The reason is because Fibonacci sequence starts with *two* known entities, 0 and 1. Your code only checks for one of them (being one).

Change your code to

```
int fib(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    if (x == 1)
        return 1;

    return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);
}
```

To include both 0 and 1.

Comment: Does not the series starts from 1,1?

Comment: That's not what I've been taught, and not what Wikipedia suggests - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: @Aviator: Depends on how you define Fibonacci numbers. ;)

Comment: @Spoike, @LiraNuna: Thanks :) Got it now. Have seen some implementations starting with 1,1,2 etc.,. So got confused!

Comment: How about changing `if (x == 1)` to `else if (x == 1)`?

Comment: Or about changing both lines to `if (x <= 1) return x`. :-)

Comment: or changing to `if (x<2)`

Answer (score 10):

Why not use iterative algorithm?

```
int fib(int n)
{
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
        int c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }           
    return b;
}
```

Comment: That’s the best approach. But he asked for a recursive solution.

Comment: @Gumbo, the 'best' approach would be meta-programming, no doubt.

Comment: I never said it is, I know what meta-programming is, and it involves no runtime calculations *at all*.

Comment: I don't want to confuse the author, since he is clearly focusing on recursion. If you want to know more, visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

Comment: A metaprogramming approach would basically boil down to a recursive solution...the calculation would simply be transfered from runtime to compile-time. Claiming that this would be a better approach is non-sense because we don't know the OP requirements: if he just needs to run the program once, having a huge compile time and a short runtime is not better than having a short compile time and a long runtime. Similarly, if he needs to take as input the 'n' parameter, metaprogramming is not usable (except if you explicitely put an upper bound to this number). Moreover, compilers have a limited...

Comment: ...recursion depth, so this can be an issue. To sum up, metaprogramming is a really powerful tool, but should be wisely used, only when it truly fits the problem.

Comment: For the OP's benefit it has to be said: In 99% of real life situations, iterative run-time solution is the only option. Iterative solution is *much* faster than wrong recursive template based solution.  And *much* slower vs a proper recursive template based solution.  https://wandbox.org/permlink/43Gb20ACqmvQHdhT

Comment: The OP did not ask about another solution, the OP asked what wrong was in their solution.

Answer (score 7):

By definition, the first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1 and 1, or 0 and 1. Therefore, you should handle it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Fibonacci(int);

int main(void) {
    int number;

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    if (number < 0)
        cout << "That is not a positive integer.\n";
    else
        cout << number << " Fibonacci is: " << Fibonacci(number) << endl;
}

int Fibonacci(int x) 
{
    if (x < 2){
     return x;
    }     
    return (Fibonacci (x - 1) + Fibonacci (x - 2));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this solution is short and seem looks nice:

```
long long fib(int n){
  return n<=2?1:fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
}
```

Edit : as jweyrich mentioned, true recursive function should be:

```
long long fib(int n){
      return n<2?n:fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    }
```

(because fib(0) = 0. but base on above recursive formula, fib(0) will be 1)

To understand recursion algorithm, you should draw to your paper, and the most important thing is : "Think normal as often".

Comment: `fib(0)` wrongly results in 1. This would solve: `return x < 2 ? x : fibonnaci(x-1) + fibonnaci(x-2);`. Here an extra condition exclusively for `fib(2)` would just slow down the function.

Comment: often fibonnaci function n just runs up to about 50 with recursive call. I don't think additional condition will slow down the `recursive call`

Comment: My point was that your `fib` function returns the wrong result for `fib(0)`. Please, ignore the rest :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}
```

in fibonacci sequence first 2 numbers always sequels to 1 then every time the value became 1 or 2 it must return 1

Answer (score 2):

**This is my solution to fibonacci problem with recursion.**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibonacci(int n){
    if(n<=0)
        return 0;
    else if(n==1 || n==2)
        return 1;
    else
        return (fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
}

int main() {
    cout << fibonacci(8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP did not ask about another solution, the OP asked what wrong was in their solution.