# Why is my recursive function so slow in R?

Tags: algorithm, r, optimization, recursion, fibonacci

The following takes about 30 seconds to run whereas I would expect it to be nearly instant.  Is there a problem with my code?

```
x <- fibonacci(35);

fibonacci <- function(seq) {
    if (seq == 1) return(1);
    if (seq == 2) return(2);
    return (fibonacci(seq - 1) + fibonacci(seq - 2));
}
```

Comment: Where's the memoization?

Comment: In addition to implementing a better algorithm as noted above, you could also try some of the R patches that Radford Neal has been working on. http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/fourteen-patches-to-speed-up-r/

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but are you sure that is correctly implementing the [Fibonacci sequence?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_numb).  Surely your code will generate `1,2,3,5,8,...` whereas the correct sequence is `0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...` ?

Comment: Not familiar with memoization and how it is implemented in R.  I'm implementing Fibonacci as specified here http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2

Comment: Package `gmp` has the function `fibnum`, to compute fibonacci numbers in arbitrary precision. With the standard `doubles` you can get only up to `n=55` or so.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Patrick Burns gives an example in [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) of one way to do memoization in R with `local()` and `<<-`. In fact, it's a fibonacci:

```
fibonacci <- local({
    memo <- c(1, 1, rep(NA, 100))
    f <- function(x) {
        if(x == 0) return(0)
        if(x < 0) return(NA)
        if(x > length(memo))
        stop("’x’ too big for implementation")
        if(!is.na(memo[x])) return(memo[x])
        ans <- f(x-2) + f(x-1)
        memo[x] <<- ans
        ans
    }
})
```

Comment: well, that's a good idea. Inferno and memoization, that sounds really magically. We normally call that a global variable :-) But anyway, I didn't come to the idea of using recursion in linear time! Good note.

Comment: Late addition: there are several options for memoization: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262485/options-for-caching-memoization-hashing-in-r).

Comment: @hadley: Added this as an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32805564/468305

Answer (score 27):

That just provided a nice opportunity to plug [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) which allows us to add C++ functions easily to R.

So after fixing your code slightly, and using the packages [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) (to easily compile, load and link short code snippets as dynamically loadable functions) as well as [rbenchmark](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rbenchmark) to time and compare functions, we end up with a **stunning** 700-fold increase in performance:

```
R> print(res)
        test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2 fibRcpp(N)            1   0.092    1.000      0.10        0
1    fibR(N)            1  65.693  714.054     65.66        0
R>
```

Here we see elapsed times of 92 milliseonds versus 65 seconds, for a relative ratio of 714.  But by now everybody else told you not to do this directly in R....   The code is below.

```
## inline to compile, load and link the C++ code
require(inline)

## we need a pure C/C++ function as the generated function
## will have a random identifier at the C++ level preventing
## us from direct recursive calls
incltxt <- '
int fibonacci(const int x) {
   if (x == 0) return(0);
   if (x == 1) return(1);
   return (fibonacci(x - 1)) + fibonacci(x - 2);
}'

## now use the snipped above as well as one argument conversion
## in as well as out to provide Fibonacci numbers via C++
fibRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(xs="int"),
                   plugin="Rcpp",
                   incl=incltxt,
                   body='
   int x = Rcpp::as<int>(xs);
   return Rcpp::wrap( fibonacci(x) );
')

## for comparison, the original (but repaired with 0/1 offsets)
fibR <- function(seq) {
    if (seq == 0) return(0);
    if (seq == 1) return(1);
    return (fibR(seq - 1) + fibR(seq - 2));
}

## load rbenchmark to compare
library(rbenchmark)

N <- 35     ## same parameter as original post
res <- benchmark(fibR(N),
                 fibRcpp(N),
                 columns=c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
                           "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"),
                 order="relative",
                 replications=1)
print(res)  ## show result
```

And for completeness, the functions also produce the correct output:

```
R> sapply(1:10, fibR)
 [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
R> sapply(1:10, fibRcpp)
 [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
R>
```

Comment: Hmmm, Rcpp... really nice and easy as it seems!! Nice ;-) It also seems you try to justify exponential algorithms ;)

Comment: Hm, at 92 ms for the compiled code, it's not implementing the exponential algorithm, even on a fast computer. The compiler must be optimizing in some clever way. I don't think this is a fair test.

Comment: The inline package is driven by R and hence gets the standard gcc/g++ options.  So I call it a fair test :) because it shows you the compilercan do for you if you translate an R three-liner into a C++ three-liner.  In any event, you can study the asm code if you really want to.

Comment: Heh, all true. But it doesn't illustrate whether and where R has inefficiencies in its interpreter. Which is more relevant to us who think that calling C from R is an admission that R is fundamentally a broken language (or, at least, a fundamentally broken implementation of S).

Comment: With all due respect, that is nonsense.  Any given system will have a particular weakness.  My point is that we can build better systems by combining the relevant strengths---and can even do so easily as this example showed---and not to get uptight over the weaknesses. See for example Chambers' presentation at Stanford from last fall: It is *always* about combining languages and tools. And my humble point is that Rcpp helps you combine the better parts of C++ and R. But you are of course free to throw R in the bin and use whatever is fashionable this week.  Good luck.

Answer (score 15):

:-) because you use exponential algorithm!!! So for fibonacci number N it has to call the function 2^N times, which 2^35, which is heck of a number.... :-)

Use linear algorithm:

```
fib = function (x)
{
        if (x == 0)
                return (0)
        n1 = 0
        n2 = 1
        for (i in 1:(x-1)) {
                sum = n1 + n2
                n1 = n2
                n2 = sum
        }
        n2
}
```

**Sorry, edit:** the complexity of the exponential recursive algorithm is not O(2^N) but O(fib(N)), as [Martinho Fernandes greatly joked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518726/recursive-fibonacci) :-) Really a good note :-)

Answer (score 15):

Because you are using one of [**the worst algorithms in the world**](http://bosker.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/the-worst-algorithm-in-the-world/)!

Complexity of which is `O(fibonacci(n))` = `O((golden ratio)^n)` and `golden ratio is 1.6180339887498948482…`

Answer (score 6):

Because the [`memoise` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/) was already mentioned here is a reference implementation:

```
fib <- function(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(1)
  fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
}
system.time(fib(35))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   36.10    0.02   36.16

library(memoise)
fib2 <- memoise(function(n) {
  if (n < 2) return(1)
  fib2(n - 2) + fib2(n - 1)
})
system.time(fib2(35))
##    user  system elapsed 
##       0       0       0
```

Source: [Wickham, H.: Advanced R, p. 238.](https://books.google.de/books?id=G5PNBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA238&ots=kWnSTJre8A&dq=memoise%20package%20r%20fibonacci&pg=PA238#v=onepage&q&f=false)

In general memoization in computer science means that you save the results of a function so that when you call it again with the same arguments it returns the saved value.

Comment: would be useful if you added a sentence or two on what the ``memoise`` package does, generally speaking.

Answer (score 5):

A recursive implementation with linear cost:

```
fib3 <- function(n){
  fib <- function(n, fibm1, fibm2){
    if(n==1){return(fibm2)}
    if(n==2){return(fibm1)}
    if(n >2){
      fib(n-1, fibm1+fibm2, fibm1)  
    }
  }
fib(n, 1, 0)  
}
```

Comparing with the recursive solution with exponential cost:

```
> system.time(fibonacci(35))
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
   14.629     0.017    14.644 
> system.time(fib3(35))
  usuário   sistema decorrido 
    0.001     0.000     0.000
```

This solution can be vectorized with `ifelse`:

```
fib4 <- function(n){
    fib <- function(n, fibm1, fibm2){
        ifelse(n<=1, fibm2,
          ifelse(n==2, fibm1,
            Recall(n-1, fibm1+fibm2, fibm1)  
          ))
    }
    fib(n, 1, 0)  
}

fib4(1:30)
##  [1]      0      1      1      2      3      5      8
##  [8]     13     21     34     55     89    144    233
## [15]    377    610    987   1597   2584   4181   6765
## [22]  10946  17711  28657  46368  75025 121393 196418
## [29] 317811 514229
```

The only changes required are changing `==` to `<=` for the `n==1` case, and changing each `if` block to the equivalent `ifelse`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg not at all! Fell free to do it.

Comment: I also changed the initial conditions to be `n, 1, 0` to be mathematically correct, but that doesn't change the runtime or the meaning of the original code.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg nice, I also liked the `Recall` edition

Answer (score 2):

If you are truly looking to return Fibonacci numbers and aren't using this example to explore how recursion works then you can solve it non-recursively by using the following:

```
fib = function(n) {round((1.61803398875^n+0.61803398875^n)/sqrt(5))}
```

Comment: This function is accurate up to `n=55`.