# not using for loop in R for recursion?

Tags: r

I wonder how I can code recursion not using a `for` loop
for a vector? Will it be more efficient?

My `for` loop code:

```
fib <- function(n){

  if (n==2){
    return c(1,1)
  }
  if (n==1){
    return c(1)
  }

  v=c(1,1)
  for (i in 3:n ) {
    v=c(v,v[i-1]+v[i-2])
  }  

  return(v)

}
```

I look at a post and it says it is not efficient to append to a vector in R as the whole vector is re-created?

Comment: First off, your base cases are not valid r syntax.  You may want `rep(1,2)` and `1` respectively for those (i.e. the brackets are not valid).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6807068/1412059

Comment: Hi Roland. Thanks for the reply. I want to series not the sum

Comment: Thanks devmacrile for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer your question about generating the Fibonacci series without a for loop but a fast solution could be to use `Rcpp`. Code recursion without growing the resulting vector becomes messy.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]                                                                                               
NumericVector fib(int n) {

  NumericVector res(n);

  if (n==0)
    return(res);

  res(0) = 1;

  if (n>1) {
    res(1) = 1;

    for (int i=2; i < n ; i++) {
      res(i) = res(i-1) +   res(i-2);
    }
  }
  return(res);
}
```

You can compile the code using

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(file="fib.cpp")

# Test
fib(5)
fib(100)
```