# Can R save objects made by a function for future use?

Tags: r, memory-management, fibonacci

Currently I'm working on a R project which includes following code.

```
vec <- 1:25
fib <- function(x)
{ if (x==0) return (0)
 if (x==1) return (1)
 if (x==2) return(2)
 return(fib(x-1)+fib(x-2))
}
lapply(vec,fib)
```

I just want to know that, how does R compute the fibonacci function in a code like this? More simply, when it comes to number 25 in vector "vec" does R compute the whole function, or can R compute the fib(25) using the values of fib(24) and fib(23)  since they have been computed already?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807068/why-is-my-recursive-function-so-slow-in-r) a similar post.

Answer (score 2):

It will compute all the recursive values one by one by default, but you can use an external package like `memoise` to cache previous values, or do it yourself. Have a look at the [following blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fibonacci-sequence-in-r-with-memoization/) which shows this using a Fibonacci function as well.